# Regex replace anything but multiple occurence of group

Tags: python, regex, oracle

I am trying to find a proper regex to replace anything in a string but a group preceded by a certain pattern.

Suppose I have records like these:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum duo dolores, tempor et ea rebum.
L. i. sed diam; duo dolores. Lorem ipsum tempor et ea. Duo dolores
L.i. nonumy eirmod tempor et ea rebum. L. i. consetetur sadipscing.
```

I want to replace anything in the strings but what is preceded by a variant of lorem ipsum. I wish to have the following outcome:

```
dolor sit amet; duo dolores
sed diam; tempor et ea
nonumy eirmod tempor et ea rebum; consetetur sadipscing
```

I tried the following code to capture the group but am not able to capture the second occurrence of the group.

```
'.*((Lorem ipsum)|(L\. *i\.)) ([0-9A-Za-z]+)+.*','\4; '
```

I suspect it has to with the second `.*` among other reasons. 
I'm trying to do this in Oracle 11g but am not opposed to doing this with Python.

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace the things with? How many words after `Lorem Ipsum` do you want to capture? What do you want to do with that captured group afterwards? Could you please elaborate, step by step

Comment: Is there a reason why you have pairs on each line separated by a semi-colon such as `dolor sit amet; duo dolores` rather than just separate strings?

Comment: Python: https://ideone.com/qWybdW. Does it work for you?

Comment: `amet,` ends on a comma, while the expected is `amet;`. Also for `rebum.` and `rebum;` Is there a rule for the punctuations?

Comment: @Nilsic Take a look at this [expression](https://regex101.com/r/HBuB3A/1). I don't know how to do it without the trailing `;` unless you add a programmatic element.

Comment: @Chase I want to replace anything but the desired string with an empty string, extracting what I have described in my post. The amount of words after `Lorem Ipsum` is dynamic; anything after `Lorem Ipsum` until any punctuation is to be captured. The captured group should be extracted/printed and if the captured group occures multiple times, I want it to be separated by `;`.

Comment: @DarrylG There is no specific reason in having the semi-colon as a separator instead of separate strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your solution in Python! I will try to adapt this to my actual problem.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I used different puctuation just to give an example that I am dealing with exactly that.

Comment: @oriberu I like your solution a lot! The negative lookbehind you used seems to be what I was struggling to find.

Answer (score 2):

To detect the individual strings:

```
# Regex Pattern
pattern = r'(?:(Lorem ipsum )|(L\.\s?i\. ))(.*?)(?=[^\w\s])'

# Find matching string
result = [m[2] for m in re.findall(pattern, s, re.I)]

# Pattern matches
print('\n'.join(result))

print('\nFormatted into pairs')

# Display as pairs
#    Group into pairs
m = ['; '.join([result[i], result[i+1]]) for i in range(0, len(result), 2)]

#    Print Pairs
print('\n'.join(m))
```

**Output**

*Matching Patterns*

```
dolor sit amet
duo dolores
sed diam
tempor et ea
nonumy eirmod tempor et ea rebum
consetetur sadipscing
```

*Formatted into pairs*

```
dolor sit amet; duo dolores
sed diam; tempor et ea
nonumy eirmod tempor et ea rebum; consetetur sadipscing
```

**Explanation**

Using pattern:

```
pattern = r'(?:(Lorem ipsum )|(L\.\s?i\. ))(.*?)(?=[^\w\s])'

(?:(Lorem ipsum )|(L\.\s?i\. )) - non capturing group for variants of Loren ipsum
(.*?) - 'non-greedy' match any characters
(?=[^\w\s]) - lookahead to stop on non-word or space character
```

Comment: Note that the `(.*?)(?=[\.,;])` means the only "stop" punctuation supported is `.`, `,` and `;`, and it must be present even at the end of the string for it to work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew--good point. I suppose I should limit it to what he has in his example.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Now, you are basically using [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883407/regex-replace-anything-but-multiple-occurence-of-group/60884132?noredirect=1#comment107717993_60883407). Please do not use others' solutions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew--I object when you say I was using your solution since I have seen `(\w[\w\s]*)` in other posts.  But, to be non-controversial I switched to another stop pattern, namely: (?=[^\w\s]) which I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209963/combining-regular-expressions-in-python-w-and-s).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew are you sure *the my solution* link addresses the right location ?

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks for your solution. I will try to adapt this to my problem. As already stated in another comment the use of a lookbehind/lookahead seems promising.